# D3 Tree Layout: I want to use jQuery to toggle all children

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm using this example as a base:
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

In my code I start with all nodes collapsed and a user can click branches to navigate the tree as in the demo.

For user convenience I would like to use jQuery to toggle expand/collapse all children of the root. The code below will only toggle the immediate children of the root.

I've tried many options but I can't work out the correct function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$('.clicktoexpandALL').click(function(){
    toggle(root);
    update(root);
});
```

I have tried `toggle(root.children[0])` & `toggle(root.children[1].children[2]);` to no avail.

EDIT: UPDATED Question.

If I could access the `toggleAll(d)` function I'd be able to do what I want but a simple function call wont work.

d3.json("json/results.json", function(json) {
    root = json;
    root.x0 = h / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

```
function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
  }
}

// Initialize the display to hide nodes.
root.children.forEach(toggleAll);

update(root);
```

});

ADDED JSFIDDLE LINKS

with code
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/vV3Sc/

full screen
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/vV3Sc/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use the method `toggleAll`, which toggle the root node and the sub nodes under it:

```
function toggleAll(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
    toggle(d);
  }
}
```

The `toggle` method will hide/show the attribute `children` of the root, but not the children of other nodes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't call that method directly. I'll double check in the morning.